# Working with Tableviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, uitableview

Hi I am a little new to Swift and tableviews I am working on a final project at school and I am using Alamofire to make my request and SwiftyJSON to parse through my JSON. I want to store some data that is in a [[String:String]] into my tableview cell. I keep on getting this error and can't not figure out, If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

```
 var items = [[String: String]]()
var regions = ["NA", "EUW", "EUNE", "BR", "KR", "LAN", "LAS", "OCE", "RU","TR"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    regionPicker.inputView = pickerView
    regionPicker.text = regions[0];
    search.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    loadData("maj0r Lee Hung")

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


    func loadData(name: String){
    let escapedName = name.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    let url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/\(escapedName!)"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url , parameters: [ "api_key":"BLAHBLAHBLAH" ])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print(json)
                    for (key: _, subJson: json) in json {
                        let id = json["id"].stringValue
                        let name = json["name"].stringValue
                        let iconID = json["profileIconId"].stringValue
                        let obj = ["id": id, "name": name, "iconID": iconID]
                        self.items.append(obj)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type [[String:String]]

Comment: try  [String: String]() instead of [[String: String]]() and yes, items[indexPath.row] is Dictionary not string so get the value as per the key to display in tableView!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
```

The text is expecting a string, but you are passing a dictionary. You need to take the items[indexPath.row] and extract an individual string from it.

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't see that. That is what 8 hours of coding will do to you.